# Contour and perimeter recognition in binary image

Tags: algorithms, contour-integration, recursive-algorithms, image-processing

I need to detect contour (object) and find the perimeter of a detected object.

For example, I have the following image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/40TTX.png
All images are binary, so they consist of only `0` and `1`.

I need to firstly detect objects, and then find the perimeter of the object contour, the area will be known I guess because this is just the sum of all object pixels.

I am using 4-pixel coherence while finding objects.

I have found some algorithms, but cannot figure out how they work and how to implement them if I have an array of 1 and 0.

Please, can someone provide explanation or code example of the easiest to understand the algorithm.

I need to do this without using `OpenCV` or any other library.

Comment: you have to detect where the image changes fast : use a gradient or laplacian filter, and clamp

Comment: What algorithms are you having trouble with?